# android rotating animation

Tags: android, layout, animation, view, rotation

i have a layout that looks like this: (without the arrows)

[image: layout]

the pictures of the animals around the layout.
i want to make a rotating animation so that all the animals will go to to the direction 
of the arrows (actually, they should be able to rotate 360 around the view) and replace each other's location. BUT keep their own orientation - so that every animal will keep standing on her legs, and not her head :-)

I'm stuck with this problem for 2 days now, and i have no idea how to implement this

please any help?
Thank you,
Ron

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could manually animate them, like game sprites.  Another option would be opposing rotate animations:

rotate_left.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <rotate
            android:toDegrees="0"
            android:fromDegrees="359"
            android:pivotX="50%"
            android:pivotY="50%"
            android:duration="2000"
            android:repeatCount="infinite"
            android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
            />
</set>
```

rotate_right.xml

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <rotate
            android:toDegrees="359"
            android:fromDegrees="0"
            android:pivotX="50%"
            android:pivotY="50%"
            android:duration="2000"
            android:repeatCount="infinite"
            android:interpolator="@anim/lin"
            />
</set>
```

Layout xml file (just a text box on top and bottom.  You'll have to implement the 4 corners yourself ;)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
    <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:id="@+id/outer"
            >
        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center">
            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:id="@+id/top"
                    android:text="Top"/>
            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:id="@+id/bottom"
                    android:text="Bottom"/>


        </LinearLayout>

    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

In your Activity:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.[yourlayout]);

    findViewById(R.id.outer).startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.rotate_left));
    findViewById(R.id.top).startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.rotate_right));
    findViewById(R.id.bottom).startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.rotate_right));
}
```

For some reason I can't get the rotate to use the linear interpolator properly.  It keeps speeding up/slowing down.  Might have to do that in code.

Comment: and how do apply the animation? on the LinearLayout or on the FrameLayout? can you please add some code?

Comment: @RonGross Hi Ron can you please help me for FOUR corners - the same animation. I want to implement the same with four images. thnks

Comment: @KevinGalligan Can you please help me with a set of 4 images ? :(